# jquery only returns first input element from dev tools console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html:

```
<form novalidate="" id="loginform" action="" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="c" id="c" value="abc">
  <input type="hidden" name="initiation" id="initiation" value="test1">
  <input type="hidden" name="rmo" id="rmo" value="test2">
```

................

I want to select all the input elements, but when I enter:

```
$("input")
```

In the chrome devtools console, I only get the first element:

```
<input type="hidden" name="c" id="c" value="abc">
```

what can I enter to get an entire list of the input elements?

Comment: That jQuery will definitely get all the inputs.  Exactly what are you doing that makes you think otherwise?

Comment: can you try `jQuery("input").length`

Comment: It works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/RhMgJ/show/ (even if I type in the console `$("input")` after I visit the page)

Comment: what does `$("input").each( function(){ console.log(this) } );` say?

Comment: have a look at:
[.each API in Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not a stupid question. It's actually confusing behaviour brought about by Chrome developer tools.

What has happened here is that you've not included JQuery. Google Chrome has the variable/function `$` available in Chrome developer tools. It's different to jQuery.

Here is documentation about it: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/commandline-api#selector

The documentation in this case says:

> Returns reference to the first DOM element with the specified CSS selector.This function is an alias for document.querySelector() function.

So, it kind of works like jQuery, enough to fool you if you don't expect it. And it's only available in developer tools. And it is aliased when you install jQuery which installs itself in `window.$` so you'd never know (try printing `$` and `window.$` in a console on a blank window).

Fix this by adding jQuery to your HTML document.

Comment: Thanks, That makes sense. Another way (without jquery) based on your reference above is to enter $$("input") - That gives an array of all inputs. Thanks for pointing this out. I assumed $ meant jquery - Bill